# Some AccessibilityEvent not firing in JellyBean 4.2

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm coding an app specifially designed for the blind and vision impaired and I'm trying to override the behavior of `TextView` when specific `AccessibilityEvent` are fired. The screen layout consists in 4 `TextView` arranged vertically that fill the screen. I just want to change the color of the background to reflect which one is "focused" so in my custom `TextView` I have this method

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        System.out.println(event.toString());

        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER ||
                event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
            this.setBackgroundColor(mColorArray[2]);
        }

        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_EXIT ||
                event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED) {
            this.setBackgroundColor(mColorArray[0]);
        }

        return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);         
    }
```

My problem is that `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED` is never fired. The three others fire correctly when using ExploreByTouch or swiping left/right up/down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [AccessibilityService is started but does not receive AccessibilityEvents on JellyBean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019848/accessibilityservice-is-started-but-does-not-receive-accessibilityevents-on-jell)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the accepted answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019848/accessibilityservice-is-started-but-does-not-receive-accessibilityevents-on-jell)  might solve your problem. 
Be careful that if you set your target sdk to 17, there's some extra similar steps to do as described in the comments of the link.

Well I might have read this too fast, it's strange that some are fired and others are not.