# dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent does nothing JellyBean+

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I'm trying to add text to an EditText field by using the dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent method.

I do a event.getText().add("Say this additionally");

but it doesn't do anything but the event fires.  It works on my Samsung Galaxy S3, but not on the Nexus 5, or Galaxy s3 mini for example.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Adding text to all outgoing events on an EditText will break TEXT_CHANGED type events. If you need to add additional spoken context to an EditText, you may want to consider using the android:labelFor attribute instead. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. I have a AccessibilityService that shall read out any incoming notification. It does work fine with ICS , but stopped working with JellyBean. Finally i got the solution from [AccessibilityService is started but does not receive AccessibilityEvents on JellyBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019848/accessibilityservice-is-started-but-does-not-receive-accessibilityevents-on-jell) . Now its working like a charm .Hope it should helpful for you.